# Tangent plane with three variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, tangent-line, tangent-spaces

The queation is :

**Show that the sum of the squares of the intersecting axes of the tangent plane at any point ($x_0$, $y_0$, $z_0$) of the surface $x^{2/3}$ +$y^{2/3}$ + $z^{2/3}$ = $a^{2/3}$ is constant.**

My attemp with two variables using parametric subsitiution:
$x=a{cos}^{3}\theta$ , and  $y=a{sin}^{3}\theta$

and then find the tangent $\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{sin\theta}{cos\theta}$.  The tangent equation then yields a constant as shown in the attached picture.

[image]

However, I could not prove it for three varialbles,

Any idea,

Comment: Can you find the tangent plane? If yes, state it. If no, show what you've tried.

Comment: Have you used the gradient? If $\phi = 0$ is a surface then $\underset{\scriptscriptstyle-}{n}=\underset{\scriptscriptstyle-}{\nabla }\phi $ at a point is a vector normal to the surface at that point.

Comment: How about taking $f(x,y,z)=x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}+z^{2/3}$ and fixing $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in f^{-1}(a^{2/3})$. Then $$\nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=\Bigg<\frac{2}{3x_0^{1/3}},\frac{2}{3y_0^{1/3}},\frac{2}{3z_0^{1/3}}\Bigg>$$ The equation of the tangent plane becomes $$\nabla f (x_0,y_0,z_0)\cdot (x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0)=0$$ which is equivalent to $$\frac{x}{x_0^{1/3}}+\frac{y}{y_0^{1/3}}+\frac{z}{z_0^{1/3}}=x_0^{2/3}+y_0^{2/3}+z_0^{2/3}$$ Since $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in f^{-1}(a^{2/3})$ we get $$\frac{x}{x_0^{1/3}}+\frac{y}{y_0^{1/3}}+\frac{z}{z_0^{1/3}}=a^{2/3}$$ Can you finish?

Comment: I could not understand your answer.. which method is this?

Comment: The equation of a tangent plane to the level set $f(x,y,z)=a^{2/3}$ at some point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ on this level set is $$f_x(x_0,y_0,z_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0,z_0)(y-y_0)+f_z(x_0,y_0,z_0)(z-z_0)=0$$

Comment: If $n$ is normal to a plane through $p_0$ then $r.n = p_0 .n$ where $r = (x,y,z)$. In your case, $n$ is the gradient vector for the surface at $p_0$. This will make sense if you know how to calculate the gradient. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: See my answer to the same question in the above link. Here the RHS is $a^{2/3}$ instead of $2^{2/3}$.

Comment: Yes I got the answer from  Matthew and Paul comments.  I needed to continue the tangent equaltion and seperate the varaibles to get $a^2$ ... Thank you

Comment: Is a queation, both a question and a creation? :-)